# Why is Char Data Type used in this Function?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm a student and was given this function by our teacher to get user input. It's used for integers but I'm confused why there's a char data type. If someone could explain this function that would be great.

```c
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)
int getNum(void)
{
    char record[121] = {0};
    int number = 0;
    fgets(record, 121, stdin);
    if( sscanf(record, "%d", &number) != 1)
    {
        number = -1;
    }
    return number;
}
```

When calling we do this for example:

```c
    int age = 0;      //we always have to initialize
    age = getNum();   //this is how we call the function to get user input
```

Comment: The user types characters on their keyboard.  They need to be converted to a number, that's what sscanf() does.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the question to include how we call it, we don't type characters when using this function though

Comment: You're reading content from stdin. stdin has characters. Doesn't matter if it's a keyboard, a file, a pipeline...

Comment: There is no point in initializing and then assigning. Just write `int age = getNum();` - this has been allowed by C for over 20 years.

Answer (score 5):

The `char record[121]` variable is actually an *array* of characters, otherwise known as a *string*. It is used here so that, if an erroneous input is given (instead of a valid *integer* input), then the input stream is still cleared by the `fgets()` call, which takes in *all* characters up to (and including) the newline character.

The `sscanf` function then attempts to extract a valid integer from the read character string and, if it fails, then an error value (`-1`) is assigned to signal that fact. If it succeeds, it assigns the given input value to `number`, in the same way that a *successful* call to `scanf("%d", &number)` would.

However, just using such a simple `scanf()` call would potentially leave 'unprocessed' characters in the input stream, which could cause problems for any subsequent input operations (or require the input stream to be cleared).

---

Using such a technique will also prevent undesired/unexpected effects caused by a user typing *extra* characters after a valid input. For example, the following (deliberately bad) code will cause a 'surprise' if you enter `1a` in response to the first prompt:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 0, number2 = 0;
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number2);
    printf("Given numbers were: %d and %d.\n", number, number2);
    return 0;
}
```

However, using the `getNum()` function your teacher provided, the following code is much more robust:

```c
int main()
{
    int number = 0, number2 = 0;
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    number = getNum();
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    number2 = getNum();
    printf("Given numbers were: %d and %d.\n", number, number2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you & To make sure I understand... This function is written like this in case of invalid input in the form of character values?

Comment: @Joey. Yes - the *main* point of such code is to more easily handle invalid input. You have a good teacher: although it's slightly more work than using a simple `scanf("%d", &number);` line, you are being taught a good programming technique.

Answer (score 0):

The program is reading lines from a file with fgets, which uses a string as storage buffer for the line. After that it processes the line to find a string that can be read as an int (%d), checks if that operation went OK, and returns the integer if so.

Answer (score 0):

The function is reading input as text, storing it to the character *array* `record`.  It then converts that string into an equivalent integer value using `sscanf`.

This is a bit safer than just using `scanf` directly - it ensures that if the user types non-numeric input, it's still consumed from the input stream so that it doesn't cause problems later on.